# Npm extract div in another file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I use webpack to build an index.html file like this when i launch "npm run build"

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="root">
     <div>My app</div>
     <div>My first content</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want a script or anything else to extract only my "div with root id" in another html file call "custom.html"

The results will be a custom.html file with only

```
<div id="root">
   <div>My app</div>
   <div>My first content</div>
</div>
```

Do you have any solution to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: you could use a Handlebars for this.

Comment: Do you have any exemple ?

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/ just follow how to use partials. You can manually add different .hbs files into other .hbs files. Since .html files wont allow this.

Comment: Possible to extract automatically in a external html file ?

Comment: Any exemple with my config ?